# Why does WP_Query strip colons from tag names?

Tags: taxonomy, tags

I'm using WP_Query to select a specific set of posts:

```
$args = array ( 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name'=>'exercise', 'tag' => 'org:abc' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but, when I run the query, it seems to be stripping the colon (:) in the tag name, so the query (when you output it) is searching for tag='orgabc', rather than 'org:abc'.

This also seems to happen with =, i.e. 'org=abc'

I've had to change my taxonomy as a result, but does anyone know why the colon is being stripped? is this a special character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tag` parameter should be the tag's *slug*. If you look at your tag's archive URL (the *view* link when editing the tag), it won't have the colon in it, because that's not a legal character in a URL.

Your tag's *name* can still have the colon, and you can use the URLencoded version of a colon `%3A` in the slug if you want, though you will have to manually enter that in the slug field.